# Sympy -- Simplify and gather different variables for variable transformation

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

In a `sympy` expression I would like to gather all sub expressions of `(x*y)`
and replace it by `z`, wherever possible. In a very simple example, that means performing the map

```
x*a*y+ (x*y**2) -> a*(x*y) + (x*y)*y -> a*z + z*y
```

---

The full code is with another example is

```
from sympy import symbols,Function,Derivative
from sympy import simplify, exp, cos, sin,log

x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
a,b,c = symbols('a b c')
f,g   = Function('f')(x),Function('g')(x)
```

```
# Simplify the expression such that all combinations of (x*y) can be replaced by c
expr_1 = ((x**2+y)*y*exp(-c+2*log(x*c*y)))/(x**3*c*y**2)

#simplify(expr_1) ?
```

In a final step, I would like to replace two functions `f*g` by `h`

```
expr_2 = f*g + f*Derivative(g,x) + Derivative(f*g, x) -> h + f*Derivative(g,x) + Derivative(h, x)
```

Comment: In your example both `x*b` and `x*y` are replaced with `z`. Is that intentional? If so I don't really understand what it is that you want to do...

Comment: That was a typo. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes an algebraic substitution will do what you want:

```
>>> eq
a*x*y + x*y**2
>>> eq.subs(x,z/y)
a*z + y*z
```

But you could just as well have done `subs(y,z/x)` but that would not have led to as simple of an expression. In such cases you can try both and take the simpler of the two:

```
>>> from sympy import ordered
>>> next(ordered([eq.subs(x,z/y),eq.subs(y,z/x)]))
a*z + y*z
```

For `expr_1`

```
>>> eq=((x**2+y)*y*exp(-c+2*log(x*c*y)))/(x**3*c*y**2)
>>> next(ordered([eq.subs(x,z/y),eq.subs(y,z/x)]))
c*z*(x**2 + z/x)*exp(-c)/x**2
>>> next(ordered([eq.subs(x,c/y),eq.subs(y,c/x)]))
y**2*(c**2/y**2 + y)*exp(-c)
>>> simplify(_)
(c**2 + y**3)*exp(-c)
```

The `ordered` strategy should also work for `expr_2`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. (a*b) was a typo and has been replaced.